# Using significant figures, what would the answer be?

Tags: physics, data-analysis

I've been learning about significant figures and I have a few questions.

When you multiply/divide, the number of significant figures in the answer should be the same as the term with the least number of significant figures. But what about in a situation where the answer just has more significant figures?

For example, what if you have `12^2`. This would be the same as `12 x 12`, right? And if that's true, then the answer should have only 2 significant figures. So would I round the answer(`144`) to `140` so it has the correct number of significant figures?

Also, in my physics book, it says

> Convert the following to SI units:
>
> a. 60 mph
>
> b. ...
>
> c. ...

But it seems as if they're treating `60 mph` as having 2 significant figures because their answer is `27 m/s`. But from what I've learned, `60 mph` only has 1 significant figure and therefore the answer would be rounded to `30 m/s`

Can someone please shed some light on both these situations?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does it seem like they're treating it as if it has two?

Comment: It would depend on the exact phrasing of the question. You haven't told us what the question is.

Comment: I've updated the post to explain more. Thanks! @HDE226868  PaulSundheim

Comment: Something to think about: if you take the first two sig figs of $12.3$ and square the result you get $12^2=144$, which is $140$ when rounded to two sig figs. But note that if you round $12.3^3=151.29$ to two sig figs, you get $150$. Weird, no?

Comment: @DavidH I see that is strange. But if you square **12.3**, wouldn't you round it to 3 sig figs? Or is that wrong?

Comment: You would round to three sig figs after you got the result, as long as no other number has less than three sig figs. Don't round too early - my chemistry teacher always reminded us of that!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: It is clearer in scientific format e.g. $6 \times 10^1$ versus $6.0 \times 10^1$.  With $60$ you don't know whether the second digit is known to be $0$ or just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Multiples of numbers like `60 mph` may have 2 significant figures or 1 depending on the context. Keep in mind that significant figures are used when dealing with physical data, so how the value was obtained is important. If I have a speedometer that only reads every 10 mph, then 60 mph has 1 significant figure, but if it reads every 1 mph, then 60 mph has two significant figures. The point is, it depends if the 0 is simply a place holder, or if it was actually measured. If it was measured your textbook should have mentioned the convention of placing a dot above the zero. If they didn't follow this convention, your textbook might have expected something of you that apparently wasn't clear.